# Programmatically adding animation effect to a (programmatically added) popupWindow in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

So, I have a programmatically added PopupWindow which looks like this:

```
        dialog = new PopupWindow(context);
        dialog.setContentView(ll);
        dialog.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP, -70, 0);
        dialog.setWidth(w);
        dialog.setHeight(h - 50);
        dialog.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        //The dialog.update is somewhere else, I didn't bother adding it too as it is not important for this matter (I guess)
```

What I want to do is to have some sort of animation effect , like it pops right from the button I press so the popup appears. (this is just an example, I just want any sort of animation).

Documentation would be ok too, as long as it is not XML based (I found those already -not really helping me).

If other details are needed ,I will comment or edit the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I managed to deal with this problem.

There are three simple steps to achieve the animation effect.

First:
    Make two XMLs that are the animation.In my case were those two following down here.
  animation_on.xml

```
 <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:toXScale="1.0"              
  android:fromXScale="0.0"            

  android:toYScale="1.0"
  android:fromYScale="0.0"

  android:pivotX="0%"
  android:pivotY="50%"


  android:startOffset="100"
  android:duration="300" />
```

animation_off.xml

```
   <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:toXScale="0.0"              
   android:fromXScale="1.0"            

   android:toYScale="0.0"
   android:fromYScale="1.0"

   android:pivotX="0%"
   android:pivotY="50%"


   android:startOffset="100"
   android:duration="300" />
```

Second:

```
<style name="animationName" parent="android:Animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_on</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/animation_off</item>
</style>
```

Third:

```
 dialog = new PopupWindow(context);
 // ....other code, whatever you want to do with your popupWindow (named dialog in our case here)
 dialog.setAnimationStyle(R.style.animationName);
```

If anyone needs help with this, leave comment.I will answer as fast as I can.

Answer (score 12):

Here is code for setting animation style. Make sure you call setAnimationStyle method before calling showAtLocation.

```
dialog = new PopupWindow(context);
dialog.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
```

Hope this helps.

Reference: [setAnimationStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setAnimationStyle(int))

Comment: Well, sorry but it didn't really help me.

What I needed was the XML logics.

ANyways, I figured out.

Gonna post the answer later on ,as right now I am sort of bussy with another problem.

Comment: No, is not that it didn't work, is just that your answer is not what I was looking for.

I needed the XML stuff.

To be more to the point: making two animations xmls (one being the fade-in effect and the other being the fade-out effect) and I needed to create a style (in values ->styles) with those two XMLs. This is what I needed.Although, I am going to give you an UP ,as you answered promptly and I am pretty sure you would have helped me ,if I asked in the comments.